# Compilation error in find in a std::map of string, long

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-errors, stdmap

I am working on Visual Studio 2013 in VC++.
I have a std::map as follows,

```
std::map<std::string, unsigned int> myMap;
```

as a static member of a class.

I populate values into it by doing this,

```
string key = "value";
std::map<std::string, unsigned int>::iterator it = myMap.find(key);

if(it == myMap.end())
    myMap.insert(std::pair<std::string, unsigned int> (key, 1));
else
{
    int prev_value = it->second;
    prev_value++;
    myMap.insert(std::pair<std::string, unsigned int> (key, prev_value));
}
```

This does not compile and I get this compilation error,

```
1   IntelliSense: no suitable user-defined conversion from "std::_Tree_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<std::pair<const std::string, long>>>>" to "std::_Tree_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<std::pair<const std::string, unsigned int>>>>" exists  c:\filename.cpp 15
```

15 is this line,

```
std::map<std::string, unsigned int>::iterator it = myMap.find(key);
```

and this error,

```
2   IntelliSense: no operator "==" matches these operands
        operand types are: std::_Tree_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<std::pair<const std::string, unsigned int>>>> == std::_Tree_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<std::pair<const std::string, long>>>> c:\filename.cpp  17
```

line 17 is this,

```
if(it == myMap.end())
```

Can somebody help me to solve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: The error message suggests that `myMap` is actually of type `std::map<std::string, long>`, not `std::map<std::string, unsigned int>` as you claim. To avoid having to guess the correct type for the iterator, just use `auto`, as in `auto it = myMap.find(key);`

Comment: Note also that `myMap.insert` would not replace the value for an already-existing key. The whole passage can be replaced with `++myMap["value"];` - this does the right thing both for new and for existing key.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Arg, you beat me to it. Like by an hour. I should have loaded the comments before posting my answer. You've summed up my entire answer in 2 simple comments :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You [wouldn't be getting this error](http://ideone.com/4sE8L6) if your declaration were actually:

```
std::map<std::string, unsigned int> myMap
```

You would [get this exact error](http://ideone.com/s5B3n6) however if your definition were perchance:

```
std::map<std::string, long> myMap
```

---

In his famous [Almost Always Auto](https://herbsutter.com/2013/08/12/gotw-94-solution-aaa-style-almost-always-auto/), Herb Sutter postulates the guideline:

> Remember that preferring `auto` variables is motivated primarily by correctness, performance, maintainability, and robustness—and only lastly about typing convenience.

As Herb Sutter suggests `auto` (and [`make_pair`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/make_pair)) would not only make your code correct, but also make it more robust, that is it would support `myMap` independent of the declaration of which of the above declarations you used:

```
const string key = "value"s;
const auto it = arg.find(key);

if(it == arg.end()) {
    arg.insert(make_pair(key, 1));
} else {
    int prev_value = it->second;
    prev_value++;
    arg.insert(make_pair(key, prev_value));
}
```

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](http://ideone.com/NfB1qa)

**EDIT:**

[Igor Tandetinik has reminded me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41518080/compilation-error-in-find-in-a-stdmap-of-string-long/41518388?noredirect=1#comment70258186_41518388) that [`map::insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert):

> Inserts element(s) into the container, if the container doesn't already contain an element with an equivalent key

Meaning that your entire `else`-block doesn't do anything, cause it only fires when the `map` does already contain an element with an equivalent key. Presumably you intended to use [`map::insert_or_assign`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert_or_assign) or similar, in which case your entire code should simply be replaced by:

```
++myMap["value"s]
```

**EDIT2:**

Note that the above works because in C++ the subscript operator has higher precedence than the prefix increment operator. But <strike>`myMap["value"s]++`</strike> will not work because the postfix increment has higher precedence than the subscript operator. See the [C++ operator precedence chart](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) for more information on operator precedence.

And this ordering is a good thing in this case as it forces you to better coding decisions. Specifically, in C++ best practice is to use the *prefix* increment operator not the *postfix* increment operator for optimization reasons (though in most cases modern compilers will clean this up for you the best practice still stands.)

Comment: *"would vastly simplify"* Not merely simplify, but fix a bug. In the original code, the whole `else` clause is an elaborate no-op, so the map only ever contains `1`s.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Presumably this code would have been run iteratively so the else condition would have an impact...

Comment: It can't possibly have an impact - it has no side effects.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik My assumption along with iteration was that `key` would change.

Comment: Do you expect that `key` would change between `arg.find(key)` and `arg.insert(make_pair(key, prev_value))` calls? Because otherwise, `insert` is called with a key that's known to exist in the map, in which case `insert` is a no-op.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Arg. Every time I read [`insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert) I thought [`insert_or_assign`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert_or_assign) I need to update my answer to include that information.

Comment: Thanks all! My declaration was not of "unsigned int", it was a "long". Thanks for the replies. Also thanks @Igor Tandetnik for pointing out that if the value existed it wouldnt replace it. I am changing the code to do this,
string key = "key1";            //user given
myMap[key1]++;
That should work and do the trick right? I am trying to increment the value that already existed.

Comment: @s_s NO. `myMap[key1]++` will not work. `++myMap[key1]` or `(myMap[key1])++` is what you need to use, I've updated my answer to explain more completely.